# How to Set different frontname for same module in magento

Tags: magento

my module config.xml

```
<frontend>
       <routers>
            <news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </news>
        </routers>
</frontend>

<global>
        <rewrite>
            <news_url>
                <from><![CDATA[/news\/(.*)/]]>
                </from>
                <to><![CDATA[news/index/view/url/$1/]]>
                </to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </news_url>
        </rewrite>
</global>
<admin>
        <routers>
            <news>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </news>
        </routers>
</admin>
```

I am also using rewrite url as shown above. It is working correctly in frontend but in admin end if i enter news in url it is redirect to frontend. How to solve this. I also tried different frontname for admin end. It is showing index controller with values list but  unable to add new or edit  news from admin end.

Answer (score 1):

You could try either

Changing the frontname for admin

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <news>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_News</module>
                    <frontName>news_admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </news>
        </routers>
</admin>
```

Or

Use after="Mage_Adminhtml"

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Test_News after="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_News_Adminhtml</Test_News>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: HI, I followed your 1st answer i can get the grid view but unable to add or edit existing posts. IN 2nd answer i cannot able to get frontname

Comment: Please add your controller path and file name